# Control USART RTS pin from driver on embedded board

Tags: linux-device-driver, uart

I'm porting the [lirc_serial kernel module](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/drivers/staging/media/lirc/lirc_serial.c) to work on our embedded board.  We only need to implement the IR transmitter function.

For only the transmitter, the custom driver need only control the RTS pin on `/dev/ttyS0`, *from within the module.*

On standard hardware, the driver loads:

```
00:05: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
```

**NEW APPROACH**

I have not figured out how to deactivate the current driver for the serial port, so rather than create a new driver, how would you use the current *8250-dw* driver to change the RTS pin on behalf of my kernel module? Something like this?

[image: Driver stack]

Using line disciplines per this article on the slip driver looked promising, Just take *slip.c* and remove the network side of the code. But it needs a user space program (`slattach` or `dip`) to open */dev/ttyS0* and activate the line discipline.

Is that possible (or a good idea) from within a kernel module?

[image: From https://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html]

In this similar question, [How do I open/write/read a uart device from a kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045615/how-do-i-open-write-read-a-uart-device-from-a-kernel-module), [Ian Abbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott) suggested backporting serdev to kernel 4.9.

That's getting a bit involved and we're already behind schedule.  Is there an easier way?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

However, the embedded board (based on the [BayTrail Atom E3845](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/78475/intel-atom-processor-e3845-2m-cache-1-91-ghz.html)) has the serial port controller in memory mapped I/O:

```
80860F0A:00: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x90a0c000 (irq = 39, base_baud = 2764800) is a 16550A
80860F0A:01: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x90a0e000 (irq = 40, base_baud = 2764800) is a 16550A
```

I'm new to driver development. I guess `0x90a0c000` is the physical address of the controller?

To probe the module, I first remapped `0x90a0c000` to a virtual address using `ioremap_nocache` and then tried to reserve the memory using `request_mem_region`. That failed.

```
ioVirtBase = ioremap_nocache(iommap, 8);

TQTRACE("ecp_serial_probe: devm_ioremap for MMIO 0x%X returned 0x%X\n", (uint32_t)iommap, (uint32_t)ioVirtBase);
if (ioVirtBase != NULL)
{
    tqDumpBuffer(ioVirtBase, 8);
}

tqRes = request_mem_region((uint32_t)ioVirtBase, 8, ECP_DRIVER_NAME);
TQTRACE("ecp_serial_probe: request_mem_region for 0x%X returned 0x%X\n", (uint32_t)ioVirtBase, (uint32_t)tqRes);
if (!tqRes)
{
    TQTRACE("ecp_serial_probe: Cannot request memory at 0x%X\n", (uint32_t)iommap);
    return -ENXIO;
}
```

Is this the correct order of the functions?

Also, it seems `request_mem_region` fails because the device is under control of `80860F0A` ??  There is no such entry in `lsmod` but there is an entry in `/sys/devices`.

Do I need to unload that driver to control the USART?  How?

```
# ls -l  /sys/devices/platform/80860F0A\:00
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  8 23:30 driver -> ../../../bus/platform/drivers/dw-apb-uart
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  9 17:02 driver_override
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  9 17:14 firmware_node -> ../../LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/80860F0A:00
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  9 17:02 modalias
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jul  9 17:02 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  8 23:30 subsystem -> ../../../bus/platform
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Jul  8 23:30 tty
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jul  9 17:02 uevent
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Jul  8 23:30 VCOM0001:00
```

dmesg output below.  Dumping the data at the remapped virtual address is not consistent.  Sometimes all 0xFF, other times, `00 00 00 00 41 02 1C 48`. I don't understand that either...

```
MARK Tue Jul 9 17:45:35 SGT 2019
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_exit_module()
Spectre V2 : System may be vulnerable to spectre v2
ecp_serial: loading module not compiled with retpoline compiler.
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_init_module()
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_init()
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe() iommap=0x90A0C000
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe: devm_ioremap for MMIO 0x90A0C000 returned 0xE3296000
ecp_serial: Dump address 0xE3296000:
      00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
0000  FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe: request_mem_region for 0xE3296000 returned 0x0
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe: Cannot request memory at 0x90A0C000
platform ecp_serial.0: lirc_dev: driver ecp_serial registered at minor = 0

MARK Tue Jul 9 17:46:08 SGT 2019
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_exit_module()
Spectre V2 : System may be vulnerable to spectre v2
ecp_serial: loading module not compiled with retpoline compiler.
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_init_module()
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_init()
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe() iommap=0x90A0C000
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe: devm_ioremap for MMIO 0x90A0C000 returned 0xE32A2000
ecp_serial: Dump address 0xE32A2000:
      00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 
0000  00 00 00 00 41 02 1C 48 
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe: request_mem_region for 0xE32A2000 returned 0x0
ecp_serial: ecp_serial_probe: Cannot request memory at 0x90A0C000
platform ecp_serial.0: lirc_dev: driver ecp_serial registered at minor = 0
```

**What proc/iomem has to say**

```
90a0c000-90a0cfff : 80860F0A:00
90a0e000-90a0efff : 80860F0A:01
```

So indeed, the memory is under control of another driver... But how to unload it if it is not listed in `lsmod` ?

```
# rmmod 80860F0A:00
ERROR: Module 80860F0A:00 does not exist in /proc/modules
# rmmod 80860F0A
ERROR: Module 80860F0A does not exist in /proc/modules
```

**OS INFO**

```
# uname -a
Linux ecp 4.4.127-1.el6.elrepo.i686 #1 SMP Sun Apr 8 09:44:43 EDT 2018 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
# cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

Comment: *"Is this the correct order of the functions?"* -- No, you have it backwards.  Use other drivers as examples.  *"it seems `request_mem_region` fails because the device is under control of 80860F0A"* -- Typical reason for failure is that another driver has already claimed that physical memory region.  Look at **/proc/iomem** for all regions in use.

Comment: I've checked numerous other drivers and read the docs and Linux Device Drivers Vol 3.  The order of `ioremap` and `request_mem_region` is not consistent.

Comment: I've added the `iomem` info to the question

Comment: *"The order of `ioremap` and `request_mem_region` is not consistent."* -- Could you please provide the names of any drivers that have the same order as you used?  BTW the first argument of **request_mem_region()** should be a physical memory address.  Your code has a virtual memory address.

Comment: Your driver should use serdev API, which has been designed for such cases. Regarding the values, you read back all 1:s when device is in low power state, i.e. powered off.

Comment: 0andriy, that's a good idea.  I checked and serdev was introduced in kernel 4.11/4.12.  We're on 4.4 and difficult to update.  Any suggestion for 4.4 kernel?

Comment: Sorry, no idea for old kernels.